# Method of designing a function to calculate differentiation

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to calculate the numerical differentiation of a particular function. This function may vary (for example, can be a line or a circle).

My first thought is to define a generic function:

```
delegate double Function(double arg);
static double Derivative(Function f, double arg)
{
    double h = 10e-6; 
    double h2 = h*2;
    return (f(arg-h2) - 8*f(arg-h) + 8*f(arg+h) - f(arg+h2)) / (h2*6);
}
```

For a linear line:

```
double LinearLine(double arg)
{
    double m = 2.0; double c = 1.0;
    return m*arg + c;
}
```

I call:

```
Function myFunc = new Function(LinearLine);
Derivative(myFunc, 3); //Derivative at x=3
```

However, in this method I will need to hardcode the `m` and the `c` into the `LinearLine()` function.

Alternatively, if I pass `m` and `c` into the `LinearLine` argument list : `LinearLine(double m, double c)`, I will have to rewrite the `Derivative()` function return value everytime I call a different function. (For example `Circle(double radius, double x, double y)`).

My question is in such a case, what would be a good way to design such a class/function?

Comment: Side note: circle is not a function... strictly speaking...

Comment: This is not an analytic derivative, but a finite difference.The correct finite difference for the 1st derivative is `(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/(2*h)`. Where did you get your derivative from (reference?)

Comment: Read up on differentiation of implicit functions such as `g(x,y)=0` which the circle is. https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/implicitdiffdirectory/ImplicitDiff.html

Comment: I got the expression from a previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/373265/2164904

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer only applies to constructing functions to pass to `Derivative` and does not help with implicit functions (as [linked](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/implicitdiffdirectory/ImplicitDiff.html) by ja72)

You can define functions with lambda expressions:

```
  Func<float,float> myFunc = x = > 3 * x + 7;
```

You can also [curry functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to convert n-ary function to n-1-ary one:

```
  float TwoArg(float x, float y) { return x * y; }
  Func<float,float> twoArg2 = x => TwoArg(x, 2);
```